# Cannot Connect to Chromebook via ADB for Debugging

Tags: android, adb, chromebook

I'm trying to connect to my Acer Chromebook over IP to load and debug apps. I've followed the instructions here:

http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2016/12/debug-android-apps-on-chromebook-using.html

These are the same instructions you can find on Google's site. I'm in developer mode, can side-load apks, etc. From that standpoint everything is working fine. However I continue to be unable to connect using the adb connect command. It times out. I'm out of ideas. I've tried to connect to the Chromebook from several computers and none work. I can ping the ip address and get packets back so I know that much is correct.

My only other option is to purchase a different system and try that, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: I've had trouble with this too.  One problem I had was using the incorrect port, you need to use 22.  You also may need to rerun `/usr/libexec/debugd/helpers/dev_features_ssh` every time you logon to the chromebook.

Answer (score 5):

Very strange, I had this issue with port 22, so then I tried it without a port and it worked, it used port 5555.

Comment: Worked for me when I constantly get "Connection refused", even after ADB Debugging On/Off and firewall configuring

Comment: Worked for me yo use alternate port because connection with port 22 was established but in offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem** : Not able to make ADB connection on Chromebook ( DEV MODE)

**Problem analysis**: The problem can occur for the following issues
 1. Chromebook get updated on new version
 2. dev feature of SSH on chromebook get deleted by

**Solution** : 1. Press Ctrl-Alt-T to bring up ChromeOS terminal, and type shell to get bash.

2. crosh> shell chronos@localhost / $
3. chronos@localhost / $ sudo /usr/libexec/debugd/helpers/dev_features_ssh (//enable secure shell and configure firewall properly.)
   It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case (host machine Win 8.1 x64) the problem was:
1. USB3 port. After I switched cable to USB2 I saw Chromebook in windows' devices list as unrecognized device.
2. Manually install "Android ADB interface" device' driver.

After that I was able to use adb commands from host machine.